# Jenkins Failed to update Gitlab commit status

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

After updating the GitLab server certificate, the feature `gitlabCommitStatus` of the Jenkins agent stopped working.
I get the following error:

```
Failed to update Gitlab commit status for project xxxxx: Unable to invoke request: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I updated the trusted certificates in the agent machine following this [procedure](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/how-to-install-a-new-ssl-certificate), but i still got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was updating the certificates in the Jenkins slave machine instead of the Jenkins master.